# R como gerar uma série temporal?

Tags: r, séries-temporais

Gostaria de saber como faço para gerar uma série temporal de um arquivo que possui duas colunas (data e o valor), porém a data está no seguinte formato yyyy-MM-dd.

Quando uso o comando ts(), ele substitui o valo da data por um numero, por exemplo: a data(2014-01-02) virou o numero (16072). Vale citar que essa data é a primeira do arquivo, porém após o uso do ts() ela desce algumas posições, ou seja, todos os campos se misturaram.

Comment: Use xts, ts é mais limitado e funciona com dados regulares, como dados mensais, por exemplo.

Comment: Grato, vou dar uma olhada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O objeto de classe `ts` não vai entender a sua coluna de datas. Pelo contrário, elevai tentar convertê-la em algum número.

Algo do tipo:

```
> as.numeric(as.Date("2014-01-02"))
[1] 16072
```

Para criar o seu objeto `ts` você precisa usar apenas a coluna de valores:

```
> dados <- read.csv2(text = '
+ "data";"valor"
+ "2014-01-01";1
+ "2014-01-02";2
+ "2014-01-03";3')
> dados$data <- as.Date(dados$data)
> st <- ts(dados$valor, start = 2014, frequency = 365)
> st
Time Series:
Start = c(2014, 1) 
End = c(2014, 3) 
Frequency = 365 
[1] 1 2 3
```

No entanto, o `ts` não é muito bom para dados diários, uma vez que a frequência não é fixa (tem ano com 365 e ano com 364 dias).

Enfim, se você for fazer apenas manipulações e gráficos com a série não a transforme em `ts`, use apenas as funções do `lubridate` combinadas com o `dplyr` e o `ggplot2`.

Se você realmente quiser converter em formatos de série temporal no `R`, use o pacote `xts`:

```
> library(xts)
> st <- xts(dados$valor, dados$data)
> st
           [,1]
2014-01-01    1
2014-01-02    2
2014-01-03    3
```

Comment: Obrigado, vou tentar aqui.